# how to get a image link that can be put in a html code from dropbox api?

Tags: html, dropbox-api

```
    try {
        Path temp = Files.createTempFile(filename + "-", "." + extension);
        file = temp.toFile();
        //file = File.createTempFile(filename + "-", "." + extension, tempfolder);
        try (InputStream input = event.getFile().getInputstream()) {
            Files.copy(input, temp, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);


        }
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        try {
            DbxEntry.File uploadedFile = client.uploadFile("/"+filename,
                    DbxWriteMode.add(), file.length(), inputStream);
            System.out.println("Uploaded: " + uploadedFile.toString());
            String fileurl  = client.createShareableUrl("/"+filename);
            System.out.println(fileurl);
            //insertFileLink(fileurl);
        } finally {
            inputStream.close();
        }
        file.deleteOnExit();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  //log this
        status="Failure";
        message = event.getFile().getFileName() + "is not uploaded.Try again.";
    }
```

I can get links like below with the help of the code piece above:

```
https://www.dropbox.com/s/asqjcgnu5fjn2a8/photo?dl=0
```

Basically my goal is, when someone upload a photo to my website, I will store the actual file in Dropbox, and the link of the file in  my database.

I will give this link to my html files and it will be shown in the website user interface. For example someone's profile picture.

The links that I want should be like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZoHb.jpg

Hope I am clear.

Is there a way to get such links using Dropbox API?

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there with your existing code. Try adding the query parameter `raw=1` to the URL, but also make sure the file name has a good extension. (You won't be able to view the example image you gave in the browser, since Dropbox doesn't know it's an image.)

See https://www.dropbox.com/help/201 for details about viewing share links.